# Why do my dynamically added controls loose their values after Postback?

Tags: asp.net, event-handling, postback, viewstate, servercontrols

To ask my question I have created an `aspx` file containing a `Button` and a `DataList` with an **SqlDataSource**:

```
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />

    <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataKeyField="a" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" >
        <ItemTemplate>
            a:
            <asp:Label ID="aLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("a") %>' />
            <br />
            b:
            <asp:Label ID="bLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("b") %>' />
            <br />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:probaConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [a], [b] FROM [PROBA_TABLE]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

In my code behind I add `TextBoxes` to the Items of the DataList. I add to every Item a TextBox in the Page_Load, and another TextBox in the Button Click `eventhandler` as well.

```
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {   
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsPostBack)
            {
                foreach (DataListItem item in DataList1.Items)
                {
                    item.Controls.Add(new TextBox());
                }
            }
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (DataListItem item in DataList1.Items)
            {
                item.Controls.Add(new TextBox());
            }
        }

    }
}
```

This works fine except one thing. When I click the Button, the TextBoxes which were created in the Page_Load keep their Text value, but the TextBoxes which were created in the `Button1_Click` lose their Text values. My real problem is more complicated than this, but I think solving this would help me a lot.

[image: My site after postback]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each control that should receive data from page ViewState should be instantiated in **Init** or **Load** event handlers, because ViewState is persisted to controls **BEFORE Click, Change** and the rest control events (those events are triggered when ViewState changes are detected, so ViewState must be read before *Click* event is fired).

So the process should look like:

1. **OnInit** (static controls get created)
2. Static control content is deserialized from ViewState
3. **OnLoad** (create dynamic controls, in your case textboxes that you created in last Postback)
4. Dynamic control content is deserialized from ViewState
5. **Click, Change** and other events are fired according to changes detected comparing POST data and ViewState data

**Suggestions:**

You can use hidden fields to save additional status information, and then in OnLoad you can read that info to recreate dynamically created controls.

Also, you should explicitly set ID property of your textboxes so that values can be properly persisted back, don't rely on ASP.Net.

Comment: @jannagy02 If the reply helps, and is correct, accept it please. User input makes this site work.

Answer (score 0):

the http by default is stateless that means after your request is processed the server keeps no data or info of the request
but the values in the form need to be persisted in special cases when there is an error
*suppose you fill up a long form and then post it back to the server only to get an error message and all the filled up values are gone. wouldn't that be annoying*
so what asp.net does behind the scenes that it keeps a string in the page hidden that has information about all the server controls and their ids
so when you post a form back the `Page class` is created and the values that are posted back and binded in the specific controls
 because the `Page class` is being created in every request the `pageLoad` event is run and controls created in the PageLoad are then present values corresponding to their ids are put into them
 unlike the controls that are being created on button click
 till the `button_click` event is run that viewstate has already been deseralized and values are filled into them